# Athena create table from CSV file (S3 bucket) with semicolon

Tags: csv, amazon-athena

I'm trying to create a table with a S3 bucket which has an CSV file. Because of the regional settings the CSV has semicolon as a seperator and one row even contains commas.

**Input CSV file:**

```
Name;Phone;CRM;Desk;Rol
First Name;f.name;Name, First;IT;Inbel
First2 Name2;f2.name2;Name2, First2;IT;Inbel
First3 Name3;f3.name3;Name3, First3;IT;Inbel
First4 Name4;f4.name4;Name4, First4;IT;Inbel
```

**Athena query:**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `a`.`test` (
  `Name` string,
  `Phone` string,
  `CRM` string,
  `Desk` string,
  `Rol` string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = ',',
  'field.delim' = ','
) LOCATION 's3://***/test/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

**The output comes out as:**

```
Name;Phone;CRM;Desk;Rol             
First Name;f.name;Name      First;IT;Inbel          
First2 Name2;f2.name2;Name2 First2;IT;Inbel         
First3 Name3;f3.name3;Name3 First3;IT;Inbel         
First4 Name4;f4.name4;Name4 First4;IT;Inbel
```

I tried scanning the web for solutions (especially for the seperator), but nothing seems to work. I don't want to change regional settings and would love to keep the input file as is. Also if someone knows the solution for the CRM column it would be a bonus!

Comment: All your details are plain text, please paste them into the question as text rather than as a screen capture. Using code block formatting it will look the same as in your screen capture.

Comment: I changed the formattimg with blocks. Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, boy. I'm sorry you did not notice the block formatting option, you really did it the hard way!

Comment: Have a look at how I reformatted your question. The trick is that you paste the literal text (code, output, etc), then select it, and click on the `{}` icon in the editor, and it shifts everything right by four spaces, which turns it all into a code block. Or you can get the same result by putting a line with three backticks before and after the block.

Comment: Learned something new about the formatting on the site.

Comment: @Menno I am facing the exact same issue and my create table query is identical to yours except the columns. How did you fix this issue?

Comment: I didn't fix this and shamfully gave up. I made a text file out of it as a workaround